# Php checkboxs repeating

Tags: php

! want to print current month dates with checkboxes like this is march month, i start from 1-03-2013 now checkbox [] , 2-03-2013 now [] till end of the month, 31 dates and 31 checkboxes, now i have values of checkboxes in array $isActive = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];. I want $isActive values in checkboxes thats all .Following is the output of `print_r($attendancelis);`:

```
Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 5 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-03-21 11:15:17 [day_month_year] => 2323123 ) ) Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 3 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-03-12 17:47:03 [day_month_year] => 23213213 ) )
Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 0 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-03-16 13:11:58 [day_month_year] => 324234324 ) ) -->
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

$nrDaysCurrentMonth = date("t");    
for($dayNr = 1; $dayNr <= $nrDaysCurrentMonth; $dayNr++)
{
echo'<div style="width:300px;float:left;">';
echo  date(''.$dayNr.'-m-Y'); 
echo '<input name="frmEmployeeAttendance[]" type="checkbox" value="0" />'; 
foreach($attendanceList as $attendanceLis)
{
$isActivee = $attendanceLis['EmployeeAttendance']['date'];
$isActiveYM = strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($isActivee)));
$isActiveYMD = date('j', strtotime($isActivee)); 

if($dayNr==$isActiveYMD) {
$isActive = $attendanceLis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];

if ($isActive){ 
echo '<input name="frmEmployeeAttendance[]" type="checkbox" checked=="checked" value="' . $isActive . '" />'; 
}
else { 
echo '<input name="frmEmployeeAttendance[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $isActive . '" />';
}       
}


}

echo '<br/>';
echo'</div>';  
}


?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* `<br />` instead of `</br>` and `isactive` != `is_active`

Comment: Please learn how to format your code, it is IMPOSSIBRU to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, now I think I actually understand your question! :-) It only took about two days or so ;-) *lol*

Following example outputs two checkboxes under DAY 16 for the current month. The first one is checked (with value=1) and the other is not (with value=0) and day21 displays an checked checkbox (with value=1). I have not included formatting with divs and stuff but I guess you will manage anyway! :-)

```
<?php

//Example data
$attendanceList = array();
$attendanceList[0]['EmployeeAttendance'] = array('id' => 5, 'employee_id' => 8, 'is_active' => 1, 'date' => '2013-02-21 11:15:17', 'day_month_year' => 2323123);
$attendanceList[1]['EmployeeAttendance'] = array('id' => 3, 'employee_id' => 8, 'is_active' => 1, 'date' => '2013-03-16 17:47:03', 'day_month_year' => 23213213);
$attendanceList[2]['EmployeeAttendance'] = array('id' => 1, 'employee_id' => 8, 'is_active' => 0, 'date' => '2013-03-16 13:11:58', 'day_month_year' => 324234324);


//Go through all days for current month
$nrDaysCurrentMonth = date("t");    
for($dayNr = 1; $dayNr <= $nrDaysCurrentMonth; $dayNr++)
{
    echo 'Day: ' . $dayNr . '<br />';       //Show nr of current date once

    //Go through attendancelist and check where nr of dates match. 
    //Where they match, show checkboxes with active or not.
    foreach($attendanceList as $attendanceLis)
    {

        //Get this iterations date and get the number of day and put it into $isActiveYMD
        $isActivee = $attendanceLis['EmployeeAttendance']['date'];
        $isActiveYM = strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($isActivee)));
        $isActiveYMD = date('j', strtotime($isActivee)); //Day of month without leading zeros

        //Compare day of month with days loop value ($dayNr). If date from 
        if($dayNr==$isActiveYMD) {

            $isActive = $attendanceLis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];

            if ($isActive) {
                echo '<input name="frmEmployeeAttendance[]" type="checkbox" checked=="checked" value="' . $isActive . '" /><br />'; 
            }
            else {
                echo '<input name="frmEmployeeAttendance[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $isActive . '" /><br />';
            }       
        }
        //--compare day of month...
    }
    //--attendanceList loop
    echo '<hr />';
}
//-- days loop

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis) {
}
```

will iterate through the array $attendancelist twice if you have like

```
Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 5 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-02-21 11:15:17 [day_month_year] => 2323123 ) ) Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 3 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-03-12 17:47:03 [day_month_year] => 23213213 ) )
Array ( [EmployeeAttendance] => Array ( [id] => 1 [employee_id] => 8 [is_active] => 1 [date] => 2013-03-16 13:11:58 [day_month_year] => 324234324 ) ) -->
```

foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis) {
}
will iterate above row twice.

The loop

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++)
{
}
```

will do 1 iteration if $no_of_days is 1.

If you combine these above loops...

```
    foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis) {

    for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++)
    {
    //checkbox stuff here
    }

    }
```

will do iteration = ($attendancelist (nr of arrayitems) times) * $no_of_days.
Example:

- If you have 1 item in array $attendancelist and $no_of_days is 1,
  then ONE (1*1) checkbox will be shown
- If you have 2 items in array $attendancelist and $no_of_days is 1, then TWO (2*1) checkboxes will be shown
- If you have 2 items in array $attendancelist and $no_of_days is 2, then FOUR (2*2) checkboxes will be shown

You should also work on your formatting skills! :-) I hoped this helped somehow...

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php
$no_of_days = 10;

$attendancelist = array('a','b', 'c');

foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis)
{


        for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++) {

                    ?>
                <div style="width:300px;float:left;">
                    INACTIVE<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="isactive"  />
                <?php echo $start = date('' . $i . '-m-Y'); ?>
                    <br/><br/><br/>         
                </div>
        <?php
        }

}
?>
```

The above code will iterate first loop 3 times. (a,b and c), and for each iteration it would show checkboxes for 10 days.

**UPDATE again:** - if you only want to show some values for each date... ...something like this...

```
<?php
$no_of_days = 10;
$attendancelist = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$outputCheckbox = array();

//Go through all days
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++)
{

    //Show one checkbox for every date.
    foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis)
    {
        $isActive = true; //Dummy

        if ($outputCheckbox[$i] == false) {

            if ($isActive) {
                echo '<input type="checbox" value="active"><br />';
            }
            else {
                echo '<input type="checbox" value="inactive"><br />';
            }
            $outputCheckbox[$i] = true;

        }
    }
    //--attendanceList loop

}
//-- days loop

?>
```

Comment: same result foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis) {

    for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++)
    {
    //checkbox stuff here
    }

    }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: If you do a print_r($attendancelist,true) and a echo $no_of_days. What do you get then? And how many checkboxes?

Comment: If you look at the updated code example (with array a,b,c) your code should work in this manner. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you are write. my code is working like this . But i want to print check boxes only one time not three time, and all the values of is_active in foreach to put in checkboxes once

Comment: Then you will have iterate through the days FIRST, and then the attendancelist (replace the order of the loops).  Look at the update also...

Comment: Everything is ok, it prints check boxes only one time, but foreach loop lost its value, there is only one value in array, it shows only one check box true, but i have tree values of check boxes. see my code above.

Comment: What do you mean? The $isActive = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active']; must be inside of the attendance loop

Comment: yes. i need this $isActive = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active']; inside loop ,in that case i have to show checbox value.If i have three value three box should be checked.

Comment: You really lost me here... You said before: "But i want to print check boxes only one time not three time". If you delete the row : "$outputCheckbox[$i] = true;" - do you get the desired result then?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I said because of loop, if foreach repeats then for will also repeat more than once, i mean it will print months date many time.I just want current month check boxs and want to put values in that chaeckboxes .I have checkboxes values in $isActive = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];

Comment: Did my suggestion help or not? Still lost me... :-) If it didn't help - Can you give an example how you would like the result to be and can you provide a really simple example of attendanceList-array?

Comment: Yes suggestion are good .Look i want to print current month dates with checkboxes like this is march month, i start from 1-03-2013 now checkbox [] now 2-03-2013 now [] till end of the month, 31 dates and 31 checkboxes, now i have values of checkboxes in array $isActive = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active']; i want $isActive values in checkboxes thats all.

Comment: in array $isActive values are also of march month 2013,means we have to match dates then display values in correct date and check box

Comment: I've figured out your question (I hope), and supplied you with another answer :-)